# sound recognition in web

Tags: java, audio, web, sound-recognition

I am building a web page where i need to do something when a particular sound is caught by the microphone. I searched a lot and found this link :

[Write a Program Which Recognizes a Sound and Performs Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840405/write-a-program-which-recognizes-a-sound-and-performs-action)

I am stuck at two things:

1. how to use java based sound recognizers though a webpage or
   javascript
2. how to match two sounds (one from the mic. and other from saved file) using any recognizer

For sound recognizer, I am using [Sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use java sound recognizers, you will need to: either submit/stream the content recorded in the browser, or use a local processing (applet/javafx).

An [applet](http://tapas4web.blogspot.com.br/2009/11/audio-capture-applet-source-code100.html)/javafx [might not be a bad idea](http://createdigitalmusic.com/2009/06/record-it-live-to-the-internet-indaba-reveals-javafx-powered-online-recording-studio/) at all; since recording might yield a large data blob, you can do the processing in the local machine. My bet is that the applet will need to be signed to access the mic. You could also stream the audio data to the server, [websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220672/implementing-webbased-real-time-video-chat-using-html5-websockets) might be a cool shot.

For Javascript, i think you need to use [HTML5 for microphone recording](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) or [Flash](https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/).

---

For audio comparison, i think you want [audio fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_fingerprint). That is a summary of the audio file. You need to search your own database for the "best match" from what you got among what you have.

I'm not sure Sphinx is the man here. Both [Musicg](http://code.google.com/p/musicg/) and [MusicUri](http://people.seerc.org/kourtesis/musicuri/) have audio fingerprinting.

Comment: Thanx will for your reply! So now I can communicate from javascript to java applet. But the problem of matching sounds using recognizer is still there.