# How do I build ant's build.xml using NetBeans?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, ant

I've downloaded sources of one application using Subversion repository, but it turned out, that those sources were not composed to a NetBeans project. It was said in the manual, that I can build it using Apache Ant. I know, that NetBeans supports Ant by default. So here is the question - how can I tell NetBeans to run it's Ant on a specified `build.xml`?

Comment: Your question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840405/write-a-program-which-recognizes-a-sound-and-performs-action and http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/Using-NetBeans-Ant-with-multiple-custom-build-xml-targets-td3340952.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File` -> `New Project`

Then in `Categories` pick `Java` and then in `Projects` select `Java Free-Form Project` and hit `Next`. After that you will configure the project by selecting the location of the project the and build.xml and then associate targets in the build.xml with actions in the IDE.