# How to generate build file for project in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ant

I know **eclipse** can automatically create a build file for a given project through its inbuilt wizard (Export->General->Ant File).
But wondering how to do the same if my project is in **Netbeans**.

**Does NetBeans also provide a similar wizard screen to create build file. If not, any other way around.?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find to create build file from Netbeans. But found a workaround, by creating a build for my project in eclipse and then modifying it to suit to netbeans project structure.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans uses Ant as its build system. Ant build script is already there (unless you used Maven project type).

Some related questions are linked in [How do I build ant's build.xml using NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549184/how-do-i-build-ants-build-xml-using-netbeans)